How do I change the Movesense ECG Measurement Interval characteristic?
I have a Movesense device loaded with Jonas Primbs's custom movesense-ble-ecg-firmware (link below), forked from version v 2.2.1. Using a Python script and bleak, I am successful in connecting to the device and obtaining ECG voltages from the 0x2bdd characteristic. However, I have been unable to change their measurement intervals by writing to the ECG Measurement Interval Characteristic (0x2be3).
https://github.com/JonasPrimbs/movesense-ble-ecg-firmware
I have tried writing to the characteristic the allowed values: 2 (500 Hz), 4 (250 Hz), 8 (125 Hz), and 10 (100 Hz). No matter what I try to write, the read shows b'\x04\x00, corresponding to a 250 Hz sampling interval. I've tried, for example, writing b'\x10\x00', as below, b'\x10', and b'\x00\x10.
I might be making a simple mistake - I am new to Bleak, GATT services, etc.
Here's the script showing an attempt to change the ECG sample frequency to 100 Hz:
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient, BleakScanner

# BLE device name
DEVICE_NAME = 'Movesense 202930001412'

# ECG sampling rates
SAMPLE_500_HZ = b'\x02\x00' #  2
SAMPLE_250_HZ = b'\x04\x00' #  4
SAMPLE_125_HZ = b'\x08\x00' #  8
SAMPLE_100_HZ = b'\x10\x00' # 10

# ECG service and characteristics UUIDs
ECG_SERIVCE         = 0x1859
ECG_FREQ_READ_WRITE = 0x2be3
CORE_UUID = '0000{0:x}-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'
ECG_SERIVCE_UUID            = CORE_UUID.format(ECG_SERIVCE)
ECG_FREQ_READ_WRITE_UUID    = CORE_UUID.format(ECG_FREQ_READ_WRITE)

async def find_device(name):
    # Scan to get device with desired name.
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for device in devices:
        if device.name == name:
            return device
    return None

async def run(name):
    # Find device with desired name
    device = await find_device(name)
    if not device:
        print(f'Device with name {name} not found...')
        return

    # Connect to device as client
    async with BleakClient(device) as client:
        if not client.is_connected:
            print('Failed to connect to the BLE device...')
            return

        print('Connected to the BLE device.')
        
        # Write ECG sampling time
        await client.write_gatt_char(ECG_FREQ_READ_WRITE_UUID, b'\x10\x00', response=False)

        # Read ECG sampling time
        sample_freq = await client.read_gatt_char(ECG_FREQ_READ_WRITE_UUID)
        print('sample frequency', sample_freq)

        await asyncio.sleep(5)

        # Disconnect from device
        await client.disconnect()

asyncio.run(run(DEVICE_NAME))


Try changing the value on the device using a generic BLE scanning and exploration tool e.g.  nRF connect. If you can change the value with nRF Connect, then you can be confident the issue is with your script. If you can't do it with nRF Connect, then it could be there are additional steps required. Also, take a look at Bleak's Troubleshooting guide about enabling logging and capturing Bluetooth traffic as those outputs might give some clues.

Great suggestion, ukBaz. I was able to access to the device using nRF Connect and change the sampling interval. So there's a problem with the script.
I found a solution. Jonas Primbs's custom movesense-ble-ecg-firmware wants the ECG interval characteristic changed by writing to it a bytearray with the sampling rate, with the response flag set to True. So in the script above, the line should be:
wait client.write_gatt_char(ECG_FREQ_READ_WRITE_UUID, bytearray([sampling_rate]), response=True)
where sampling_rate is either 10, 8, 4, or 2 for ECG sampling intervals of either 100, 125, 250, or 500 Hz, respectively.
